# Does a temp variable maintain the order of rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, temp-tables

```
DECLARE @temp_table TABLE (order_no int, username nvarchar(100))

INSERT INTO @temp_table(order_no, username)
   SELECT TOP 10 
       user_id, username
   FROM users
   ORDER BY user_id

SELECT * FROM @temp_table
```

Will the rows in `@temp_table` always be ordered?

Comment: SQL, by its very nature, does not have intrinsic ordering of rows.  So no, it doesn't.  It doesn't as a temporary table, table variable, or physical table.  It just doesn't, period.

Comment: If you need order - the only way to get it is to specify an `ORDER BY` in your `SELECT`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that we can't guarantee the order of a variable table is because there is no default primary key, so if you add an auto incremented key which will serve as the default key then it will always follow the order of this default key. In other words, it will follow the order of insertion.

I.E.

```
DECLARE @temp_table TABLE (tempid int IDENTITY(1,1), order_no int, username nvarchar(100))
```

Answer (score 4):

The order is never guaranteed unless you explicitly use ORDER BY.

Comment: but When you put a primary key is used the implicit order is it true?, or what is happening?.

Comment: @JuanRuizdeCastilla When you use clustered key it **may** use the order but not have to.  Query Optimizer is not obliged to read data sequentially, it may for example read parallel and return in different order. Only way to be sure is `ORDER BY`

Comment: How can I check, what you say?, I mean, I know for set theory that you say its ok, but I want to check it by myself, maybe in some query, and thank you for answer. Maybe I will create a new question, what do you think?.

Comment: @JuanRuizdeCastilla See  [No Seatbelt](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/conor_cunningham_msft/archive/2008/08/27/no-seatbelt-expecting-order-without-order-by.aspx) and [Beatles-vs-Stones](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/hugo_kornelis/archive/2006/12/31/Beatles-vs-Stones.aspx) or [Without ORDER BY, there is no default sort order](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/alexander_kuznetsov/archive/2009/05/20/without-order-by-there-is-no-default-sort-order.aspx)

Comment: @JuanRuizdeCastilla Especially No Seatbelt parallelism and gather stream may break your assumption. But it will be visible with big enough structures